# How to make the color space gamma instead of linear? (for rendering)

Tags: color-management

I think by default that Blender uses the linear color space for rendering. How would I make it so that the renderers use gamma instead??

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding what color management does. Blender always renders in scene linear color space. The results can be transformed into another color space, e.g. to display it on your monitor. *Gamma* is not a color space though, perhaps you mean sRGB (IEC 61966-2-1:1999) which uses gamma correction? If your *Display Device* is set to *sRGB* and the *View Transform* to *Standard* then the sRGB Opto-Electronic Transfer Function (OETF) is used for the image that you're seeing / saving.

Comment: Maybe I should post a picture. I'm used to Unity Engine and that's what they refer to it as. Here's a picture for reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/LinearRendering-LightingSphereLinearGamma.png